# opennlp: bad class file, wrong version

Tags: java, gradle, build

When I run commands:

```
javac -cp tika/tika-2.8.0/tika-app-2.8.0.jar:opennlp/apache-opennlp-2.2.0/lib/* App.java
java -cp .:tika/tika-2.8.0/tika-app-2.8.0.jar:opennlp/apache-opennlp-2.2.0/lib/* App
```

It works perfect.

I wanted to automatize the build process with `gradle`.

So I created this directory tree:

```
$ tree -L 2 my-app/
my-app/
├── build
│   ├── classes
│   ├── generated
│   └── tmp
├── build.gradle
├── opennlp
│   ├── apache-opennlp-2.2.0
│   └── apache-opennlp-2.2.0-bin.zip
├── src
│   └── main
└── tika
    ├── tika-2.8.0
    └── tika-2.8.0-src.zip

$ tree src
src
└── main
    └── java
        └── App.java
```

my `build.gradle` is here:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation files('tika/tika-2.8.0/tika-app-2.8.0.jar')
    implementation files('opennlp/apache-opennlp-2.2.0/lib/opennlp-tools-2.2.0.jar')
}

task runApp(type: JavaExec) {
    main = 'App'
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
}
```

The output of gradle build is here:

```
$ gradle build

> Task :compileJava
/home/me/tmp/my-app/src/main/java/App.java:7: error: cannot access opennlp.tools.sentdetect.SentenceDetectorME
import opennlp.tools.sentdetect.SentenceDetectorME;
                               ^
  bad class file: /home/me/tmp/my-app/opennlp/apache-opennlp-2.2.0/lib/opennlp-tools-2.2.0.jar(opennlp/tools/sentdetect/SentenceDetectorME.class)
    class file has wrong version 55.0, should be 52.0
    Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.

> Task :compileJava FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.4.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 4s
1 actionable task: 1 executed

$ java --version
openjdk 17.0.7 2023-04-18
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.7+7-Ubuntu-0ubuntu118.04)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 17.0.7+7-Ubuntu-0ubuntu118.04, mixed mode, sharing)

$ javac --version
javac 17.0.7

$ gradle --version

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 7.4.2
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2022-03-31 15:25:29 UTC
Revision:     540473b8118064efcc264694cbcaa4b677f61041

Kotlin:       1.5.31
Groovy:       3.0.9
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.11 compiled on July 10 2021
JVM:          1.8.0_362 (Private Build 25.362-b09)
OS:           Linux 4.15.0-211-generic i386
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: You seem to be using Java 8 (class version 52), while you're trying to use classes compiled with Java 11 (class version 55).

Comment: My question isn't duplicate. Where have gradle in the duplicate? It normally works, but with gradle it doesn't work.

Comment: See the output of `gradle --version`: `JVM:          **1.8.0_362** (Private Build 25.362-b09)`. In other words, when you run Gradle, it is running Java 8, probably because your `JAVA_HOME` is configured to point to Java 8 and not to your Java 17 install. Make sure it points to Java 17 (or at least to a Java 11 or higher). In other words, the duplicate applies for your problem.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel You're right `$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-i386/` How can I find out, where is `Java 17` (Ubuntu 18.04)

Comment: Using `which java` should report the location of the executable used when you run `java` (and then use the parent directory of the bin-directory).

Comment: I set JAVA_HOME to /usr/bin/java but `$ gradle clean

ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: /usr/bin/java

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.
`

Comment: `$ file /usr/bin/java
/usr/bin/java: symbolic link to /etc/alternatives/java
`

Comment: Finally, [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1259182/13394) solved it. Thank you.